# Firebase Firestore Emulator Returning Data After Deletion?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I'm working on a React web app and I noticed some weird/unusual behavior when using the Firestore emulator...

I have an `onUpdate` trigger that is pretty basic:

```nodejs
export const onUsernameUpdateFn = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{userId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    // Retrieve the current and previous value
    const newData = change.after.data();
    const previousData = change.before.data();

    const operation = "username" in previousData ? "update" : "create";

    console.log(
      "newData",
      newData,
      "previousData",
      previousData,
      "operation",
      operation
    );

    // We'll won't update if the username hasn't changed
    if (newData.username === previousData.username) {
      console.log("Skipping because username hasn't changed");
      return null;
    }

    // Rest of the things
```

If I delete all data using the Emulator Suite (http://localhost:4000/firestore) and trigger the above code again, `change.before.data()` still has data in it...

```nodejs
functions: Beginning execution of "onUsernameUpdate"
>  newData {
>    createdAt: Timestamp { _seconds: 1652132412, _nanoseconds: 273000000 },
>    username: 'differentUsername'
>  } previousData {
>    createdAt: Timestamp { _seconds: 1652132412, _nanoseconds: 273000000 },
>    username: 'originalUsername'
>  } operation update
```

... even though the Firestore UI shows it is empty (correctly).

If I wait some time (20-30 mins or more, haven't measured) **after** the deletion, then it works as expected and the `operation` becomes `"create"` because new and previous values are not equal.

I checked and I am not running multiple emulator instances and the correct project is selected.

Is there some caching in Firestore Emulator? Is it safe to assume that when deployed, this will not be an issue?

Or... is there a better way to skip the update when the username hasn't changed, but make sure it executes when the `username` property gets written for the first time?

Note: When it works "correctly" after waiting some time, the `username` property is not present, which is what I expect.

Comment: If you can demonstrate that the emulator doesn't work the way you expect, you should file a bug report on the [firebase-tools GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) instead of posting to Stack Overflow.  If you want to know if something works when deployed, you should simply try that yourself before posting.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm asking the question in the wrong way.
Happy to edit or delete, but is there some caching in Firestore emulator that would return data in `change.before.data()` even after deletion?

Comment: That would be a question to ask in the GitHub issue to post.  Or, if you don't want to wait on someone, you could examine the source code yourself.